# SQlite3 and knexjs results in Timeout acquiring a connection

Tags: sqlite, knex.js

I am trying to run the following code and getting an error

> { TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is
>   probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Is there anyway to make sqlite wait until the pool is empty? if not, what would you suggest?

```
const path = require('path');

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    connection: {
        filename: path.join(__dirname, '/db/sqlite.db')
    }
});


knex('lorem')
        .insert({ rowid: 'Slaughterhouse Five' })

var z = 0;
while (z < 20000) {
    knex('lorem')
        .select('rowid')
        .then(result => {
            console.log('res', result);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Error in select', error));
    z++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not trying to run 20000 parallel queries. At which point would you like to wait the pool being empty? You could run all the queries one by one or you could use for example Bluebird's `.map()` which allows to pass concurrency paramater to limit how many queries are resolved at the same time.

Comment: Could you please tell me how would you change the above code and make it run one by one (as you mentioned in your post) assuming 20000 records to be inserted in the db?

Comment: for that it is probably easiest to use `knex.batchInsert('TableName', anArrayOfRows).then(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: ok I have switched to Sequelize and it handles such situations gracefully. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/

Comment: Good luck with that. Yes, sequelize is completely different level of database tool. It does all kind of magic underneath.